# TableViewCell in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have this code in Objective C and was wondering if you could translate it into the new swift Xcode... Heres the code.

```
  (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
 }
```

Comment: I refuse to believe that stackoverflow is a free translation service.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should be about right:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath);
   let cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
 }
```

Comment: this should yield the error "Use of undeclared type: 'tableView'"

Comment: This is not syntactically valid Swift. The tableView parameter is never given a type, and the indexPath parameter has the parameter's type and name reversed. This still isn't the UITableViewDelegate method in question, but it should be more like this `tableView: UITableView, indexPath: NSIndexPath`.

Comment: Fixed it!! :) now referring to the code in the method didselectrowatindexpath how can i get the string in the selected cell??

Comment: head over to apple's swift book and read about optionals — as Colin got that wrong too.